# Django context processor not setting request var in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-socialauth

I have the following view:

```
@login_required
def manage(request):
    ''' Display the list of posts that belong to the user '''
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('created_at')
    return render_to_response('posts/manage.html', {'posts':posts}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The `request` variable is empty in my template.

My settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
)
```

I want to access the logged in user through `request.user`.

What could be wrong? Thanks.

Note that I am using social auth for user login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With those context processors, you don't have access to `request` at all - but you do have access to `user` directly.

Comment: Great answer Daniel. @alexBrand, unless you also need something else from `request`, Daniel's answer saves you the extra context processor.

Answer (score 8):

Add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` `to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`